# How to check if a string contains an element of a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, contains

I'd like to to check if a string contains an element from a String array. I think that iterating all the array elements and seeing if String.contains(an element) does not seem to efficient. So I wonder if there's a more efficient way to make this look-up fast.

For example, I want to get the country name from an address string. Users can write their address without any constraints. The address string can contain the country name or city name. So I want to see if the address string has an element from an array that I will build has a bunch of country names and city names.

My current solution is:

```
 ArrayList<String> list;
 String address;
            ...
    for (String s : list) {
        if (address.contains(s))
            return s;
    }
```

This is O(n). I wonder if there's a faster solution.

Comment: Do you have some example code?

Comment: Unless the element array was extremely long, I'd just iterate.  You could alternatively build a "dynamic" regex `Pattern`, but it seems like more work than it'd be worth.

Comment: If he can store the pattern, using one would be better.

Comment: Is the code running too slowly for you the requirements? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil. -- Knuth

Comment: Use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store the names and use it to recursively check at each point in the input string if there's a match. Too much code required for me to answer, but it will perform in near O(k) time, where k is the length of the input string.

Comment: The current solution is not O(n), but rather O(k * n), where k is the length of the address. (And assuming the length of all of the n elements of `list` can be approximated to a constant.) `address.contains(s)` will take longer if the address is longer. As @Bohemian points out, using a trie (or a regexp) should perform in near O(k) time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to check if a String contains a keyword from a Set<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429697/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-keyword-from-a-setstring)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using Guava or another library with a join method.  In that case, you can build a regular expression by hand.

```
private String regex(String[] names) {
    final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";
    for (final String name: names) {
        b.append(separator);
        b.append(Pattern.quote(name));
        separator = "|";
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

The loop and the `separator` variable is the "no-if" way to join the names.  The `quote` call ensures that characters like `$`, `[`, or `.` do not mess things up.  What if one of your strings were "St. Louis"?

Then, you use `Matcher.find` to check.

```
public boolean contains(String target, String[] names) {
    String regex = regex(names);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); // Fixed, as per @Java Devil's comment.
    Matcher m = pattern.match(target);
    return m.find();
}
```

If you want to capture the matched string, enclose the regex in parentheses, and return `m.group(1)` instead.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how this compares with looping of the array and using `contains`...

Comment: Also curious, I think it would be worse, considering this loops the array anyway but adds overhead of a `StringBuilder`. Also I wasn't aware that `Pattern.compile();` accepted a `String[]`

Comment: Sorry--it doesn't.  I will edit to use `regex` in the pattern.

Comment: Instead of all that code in your regex method, try `String regex = String.join("|", names);` instead. [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) has been around for nearly a decade.

Comment: To capture the matched string, you don't need to enclose the regex in parentheses. You can use `m.group()` (with no arguments) or `m.group(0)`, both of which will return the input subsequence matched by the previous match

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to check many strings for the same array, you might improve performance by precompiling a regular expression matching all the strings in the array:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(list.stream()
    .map(Pattern::quote)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(address);
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group();
}
```

While this is more efficient in terms of complexity, compiling the regexp will have some overhead, so you are unlikely to see any performance gains unless the same `pattern` instance is used for many addresses or the address is very long and there are many strings in the list.

Also note the use of `Pattern.quote`, in case the strings contain characters that would otherwise be treated specially by regexps, like `.`.

If you're interested in complexity analysis and alternate approaches, you could have a look at [neo-search/multiple-string-searcher](https://github.com/neo-search/multiple-string-searcher) (Maven coordinates: `org.neosearch.stringsearcher:multiple-string-searcher:0.1.1`), which implements the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) and the [Commentz-Walter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm).

Answer (score -2):

You can use a for-loop to iterate through the array and check if the elements are in the String.

A better way to check if a String includes a certain string is to use the methods in the String class, such as String.contains(char). You should do some more experimenting before asking a trivial question, or at least give us some examples that can be solved directly.

Comment: He is looking for something efficient than that @Hatori check his post

Comment: And a key thing is to arrange your code so that you can break as soon as possible after finding the information required.

Comment: @Prateek I think that point is that you shouldn't try to optimize code that doesn't need optimizing.