# Elegant way to check if a String contains a keyword from a Set<String>

Tags: java, string, search, treeset

I have a `TreeSet<String>` containing some keywords. I need to test some `String`s to see if they contain any of these keywords.

I currently have:

```
String tweet = object.getText();
for (String keyword : keywords_set)
{
    if(tweet.contains(keyword))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way of doing this for a stream of Strings?

Comment: @ZouZou yes, they are

Comment: Yes I was thinking of another approach, splitting tweet by whitespaces and then for each word check it's in the `Set` (using a `HashSet`), but that would be still `O(n)` as your solution already is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aho-Corasick multiple string matching algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Comment: Can you be any clearer? How would you use the algorithm?

Comment: Um, Google: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm
Links to two Java implementations. Use one? (Or have I missed something here?)

Comment: Don't put it in the comments, put it in your answer. Explain how it achieves better efficiency or performance or cleanliness.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get any more efficient than what you have with JDK classes and methods. You need to go through each `String` in the `Set` and check if your `String` contains it.

However, you can make it cleaner if you are willing to use a 3rd party library, Guava.

With Guava, you can use [`Iterables.any(Iterable, Predicate)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#any%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) which

> Returns true if any element in iterable satisfies the predicate.

Use it like so

```
Set<String> keywords_set = ...
final String tweet = ...

return Iterables.any(keywords_set, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return tweet.contains(input);
    }           
});
```

With Java 8, it will be even cleaner thanks to [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [aggregate operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html).

Comment: Sorry, plain wrong. Your proposed solution is O(NLM) where N = number of strings in the set, L is the length of the text and M is the maximum length of the strings in your set. You want to match all of the strings at the same time to avoid scaling linearly in the size of your set (i.e. the N term in the above bound). That's what Aho-Corasick does. (BTW, I'm assuming that String.contains() uses something like Boyer-Moore.)

Comment: @user3392484 I've edited to specify that this is the best you can do with JDK classes. I'll look into the Aho-Corasick algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explicit example of how to use AhoCorasick.

[I created a branch](https://github.com/rripken/aho-corasick) of Robert Bor's java Aho-Corasick implementation that adds a "matches" method which returns true as soon as the first match is found.

Building the search trie is non-trivial. I've included an in-efficient method implementation that matches the code sample you provided.  But you really want to amortize the cost of the trie construction across a large number of searches.  To do that you really want to change your code that calls the example you included.

I included an example of how to construct the search trie once and them use it for multiple searches.

```
public boolean doesTweetMatchSlow(String tweet, Set<String> keywords_set)
{
        Trie searchTrie = new Trie();
        for (String keyword : keywords_set) {
            searchTrie.addKeyword(keyword);
        }

        return searchTrie.matches(tweet);
}

public Collection<String> findMatchingTweetsFaster(Iterable<String> tweets, Set<String> keywords_set)
{
    List<String> matching = null;

    if (tweets != null) {
        matching = new ArrayList<>();

        if (keywords_set != null && !keywords_set.isEmpty()) {

            // build trie once.
            Trie searchTrie = new Trie();
            for (String keyword : keywords_set) {
                searchTrie.addKeyword(keyword);
            }

            for (String tweet : tweets) {
                // Re-use trie for every tweet.
                if (searchTrie.matches(tweet)) {
                    matching.add(tweet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matching;
}
```